# Ubuntu 18.04 server partition becomes full randomly

Tags: 18.04, server, filesystem, partitioning, storage

I'm experiencing the following problem:

The partition `/dev/sda1` is getting used 90% or 100% randomly. It's normally on 47% and 50%, but I don't understand why it sometimes jumps up to 100%.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           796M  692K  795M   1% /run
/dev/sda1        29G   14G   16G  48% /
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      105M  3.6M  101M   4% /boot/efi
tmpfs           796M     0  796M   0% /run/user/1000
```

This happens at least once per weekend. My solution is to reboot the OS from command line, by typing `reboot`, but that is not something healthy for the server.

What could it be the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**One thing that fits your description is:**

Your `/tmp` directory getting used up by the applications running on your server and becoming full. The `/tmp` directory gets emptied upon reboot... hence the reduced partition size.

To check the usage of the `/tmp` directory please, run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo du -hsc /tmp
```

To watch the usage of the `/tmp` directory in real time, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo watch du -hsc /tmp
```

To exit real time, please press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.

---

**To empty the `/tmp` directory without rebooting**, please run the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf /tmp/{*,.??*}
```

If you get an error like `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Argument list too long`, this means your `/tmp` directory contains more files then `rm` can handle at once. To overcome this please run the following command instead in the terminal:

```
sudo find /tmp/{*,.??*} -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

If you get errors during this operation like `No such file or directory.`, please ignore them as files are being added and deleted by system all the time in the `/tmp` directory.

---

**If this solves your issue:**

You can add a cronjob to run the empty command daily.

---

**If this is not the case:**

I recommend you investigate what is eating up your space by running the following command in the terminal:

```
sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"
```

This will list all the directories and files on your system with sizes more than 1G along with their modification dates.

> To check for certain sizes:
>
> For example to list **only** directories with **3G** size, please use
>   the following command:
>
> ```
> sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[3][0-9\.]*[G]"
> ```
>
> You can change the number [3] to check for directories with say 5G
>   size like so:
>
> ```
> sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[5][0-9\.]*[G]"
> ```
>
> and so on.

Please, inspect the output with focus on recently modified ones and check if you see anything out of the norm.

You may need to continue monitoring and noting the size changes until you reach the moment where your partition is nearly full. You will then have a better understanding on what is causing this issue and will be able to make a decision.

Comment: Hello, I have this information after running  sudo du -hsc /tmp and sudo watch du -hsc /tmp 56K     /tmp
56K     total

Comment: @OscarVazquez This size for `/tmp` is normal. I recommend you investigate what is eating up your space by running in the terminal `sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"` . This will list all the directories and files on your system with size more than 1G along with their modification dates. Inspect the output with focus on recently modified ones and let me know if you see anything out of the normal. Please do not post the whole output as it may contain some confidential info. the output will be a bit large. Best of luck

Comment: the directory with bigger size is /var, this is because I have many websites inside /var/www/html. The whole /var directory is 7.9G, and /var/www/html 3.8G. What is maybe anormal is the size of /var/log which is 2.4G, should I delete old logs to free space?

Comment: @OscarVazquez No, not at the moment. I recommend you continue monitoring the size of all directories and files with the command above for a few days and note the changes until you reach the moment where your partition is nearly full. Then, please post updates here so I can suggest a good enough fix. Best of luck

Comment: Oh ok sorry, I misunderstood, thank you! I will be monitoring my directories.