# How to find the large directory which is reserving the biggest disk space?

Tags: command-line, files, disk, disk-usage, user-space

How to find (as grouped) the directory who is taking all the disk spaces?

```
# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vda1        60G   54G  6.4G  90% /
devtmpfs        1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.4G  161M  1.3G  12% /run
tmpfs           1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           285M     0  285M   0% /run/user/0
```

It does not help to see /dev/vda1 is 90%, how to check which directories having the largest disk reserve?

example:

```
/var/log/httpd    20GB
/var/log/pluto    10GB
/var/log/syslog    5GB
/var/log/tcpdump   1GB
/...              restGB
```

Comment: Try this `sudo du -hca --time / | grep -E "^[0-9\.]*[G]"` . Read here for extra info: https://askubuntu.com/a/1167390/968501

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above, files that are `open(2)`ed for write will take up diskspace. I use `bigopenfiles` to see them.

```
alias bigopenfiles='sudo lsof / | awk '\''{if($7 > 1048576) print $7/1048576 "MB" " " $9 }'\'' | sort -n -u'
```

Other "invisible" files are those which programs `open(2) O_TMPFILE` option, or have been opened and `unlink(2)`ed.

```
alias deletedfiles='sudo lsof / | egrep '\''PID|\(deleted\)'\'''
```

For example,

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ bigopenfiles
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
0MB NAME
1.03851MB /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.23.so
1.05076MB /usr/lib/firefox/browser/features/screenshots@mozilla.org.xpi
1.06348MB /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.4800.2
1.07173MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcairo.so.2.11400.6
1.07496MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexempi.so.3.2.4
1.08072MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.0.1.2
1.0952MB /usr/lib/evolution/libevolution-calendar.so.0.0.0
1.10789MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcamel-1.2.so.54.0.0
1.11092MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-datetime/indicator-datetime-service
1.11611MB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprotobuf.so.9.0.1
1.12474MB /usr/sbin/ModemManager
...
walt@bat:~(0)$ deletedfiles
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND     PID            USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE  SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
mysqld     2233           mysql    4u   REG    8,5         0  651554 /tmp/ibjp8exA (deleted)
mysqld     2233           mysql    5u   REG    8,5         0  651560 /tmp/ibaGTQ9E (deleted)
mysqld     2233           mysql    6u   REG    8,5         0  651561 /tmp/ibzy9sMJ (deleted)
mysqld     2233           mysql    7u   REG    8,5         0  651575 /tmp/ibeDES4S (deleted)
mysqld     2233           mysql   11u   REG    8,5         0  651710 /tmp/ibZSq7P0 (deleted)
dropbox    6614            walt    7u   REG    8,5         0  651721 /tmp/#651721 (deleted)
gnome-ter  7035            walt   18u   REG    8,5     65536  655802 /tmp/#655802 (deleted)
```