# Ubuntu always shows no space available and nvme0n1p8 full

Tags: 18.04

Using Ubuntu 18.04 for deep learning purposes, but when i train the model and tried to download some Python packages it always shows there is no space. I followed some advice of doing `df -h` and here is what it shows.

It always shows that `/dev/nvme0n1p8` has 19G and full used, is this what caused the problem? And also what's the difference between nvme0n1p8 and nvme0n1p7, why the distribution of the space so uneven? New to this file system so quite blur right now.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev             16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs           3.2G  1.8M  3.2G   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p8   19G   19G     0 100% /
tmpfs            16G  4.0K   16G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop1      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/111
/dev/loop3       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1353
/dev/loop2       90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8268
/dev/loop4      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop6       55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/loop5      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop0       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop7      157M  157M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/110
/dev/loop8       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/367
/dev/loop9      4.3M  4.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/544
/dev/loop10      55M   55M     0 100% /snap/core18/1279
/dev/loop11     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/loop12     150M  150M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop14     1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/81
/dev/loop13      90M   90M     0 100% /snap/core/8213
/dev/loop15      43M   43M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
tmpfs           3.2G   40K  3.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/nvme0n1p7  173G   23G  141G  14% /media/platinum/7f503035-20b1-4d19-9fb3-90eab40a784d
total           246G   42G  195G  18% -
```

Comment: Use your 'disk usage analyzer' application to find out what is taking up all your space on that storage device. That application is installed with all Ubuntu desktop systems by default.

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 18 server partition becomes full randomly](https://askubuntu.com/q/1167364/968501)

Comment: As it appears `/dev/nvme0n1p8` is where your system is installed and `/dev/nvme0n1p7` is an extra drive probably external. You need to free some space on `/dev/nvme0n1p8` in order to be able to download and install packages. Find what consumes your space and try to move it to `/dev/nvme0n1p7` which will free some space on `/dev/nvme0n1p8` and enable you to install packages.

Comment: Thanks, that helps. Can I ask how do i check what is consuming the space? @Raffa

Comment: Well, one way is to use your 'disk usage analyzer' application.

Comment: Edit your question and show me a screenshot of `gparted` and `cat /etc/fstab`. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: Or, is there any way to enlarge /dev/nvme0n1p8? like partition more disk space from n1p7 to n1p8?

Comment: Please follow the steps in my answer in the related link I posted above. After you decide on the directory that is consuming your storage the most, you can move its contents to a directory in n1p7 and create a symbolic link for it in n1p8.