# Can't find what is filling root

Tags: disk, du

Ubuntu server 20.04.1 with Kubuntu Desktop.

I have tried lots of tools like Baobab, Kdirstat, Qdirstat and Filelight.  All show my root to be about 30 GB.  However Dolphin(File Manager) and all the partition managers insist my root is nearly full.

Please help me find where the hidden files are.  There are nearly 50 GB of unaccounted for files.

[image: GParted Picture]

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @David Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does `sudo du -h --max-depth=2 / | sort -h` not give you the information you need? You'll probably need to do this a couple of times, replacing `/` with specific directory names as you dig into the file system to find where the bloat is, but `du` has always answered this question in my experience.

Comment: I'll suggest the same thing I said in [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1304270/what-is-filling-my-root-partition#comment2219315_1304270):  bind-mount `/` somewhere else (e.g., on `/mnt`: `sudo mount -o bind / /mnt`), and check `du` output on that (`sudo du -hd1 /mnt`). It's possible that some huge directory is mounted over by something else and not accessible to `du` directly.

Answer (score 0):

User @muru nailed it.  Not the first time this happened to me. I am only answering so that I can post a photo.

There was an old mount for home that needed to be deleted. That 50+ GB was exactly what the discrepancy was.

Thank you all.  A great community.
Walt

[image: GuiltyPartyFound]

[image: PartitionCorrectSize]