# Lost hard drive space

Tags: 22.04

I lost hard drive space on Ubuntu 22.04 and I don't know why.

I had more than 170GB of space two days ago. I did not install anything. Today I find that I'm losing space and it's down to 0% or 1.5% sometimes.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs           1.6G  2.0M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/sda2       641G  607G  1.6G 100% /
tmpfs           7.8G   87M  7.7G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/sda1       487M   33M  454M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.6G  252K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

Also I deleted some files and folders and I recovered more then 20GB but after restarting the PC I found just 2GB. If I open anything like Google Chrome I have 0% space.

Comment: It'd be good to see what's taking up all the space - chances are it's logs. Run `sudo du -h --max-depth=1 /var/log | sort -hr` and identify what directory is taking up the most space.  From there, we'll start hunting deeper and deeper with this but lets start here.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1167364

Comment: Here out put ... `295G /var/log
4.0G /var/log/journal
2.0M /var/log/installer
440K /var/log/apt
120K /var/log/unattended-upgrades
72K /var/log/dist-upgrade
44K /var/log/cups
8.0K /var/log/hp
4.0K /var/log/speech-dispatcher
4.0K /var/log/samba
4.0K /var/log/private
4.0K /var/log/openvpn
4.0K /var/log/lightdm
4.0K /var/log/gdm3
`

Comment: Edit your post and add the info and output there, don't put it in comments

Comment: here also `291G /var/log/syslog` if I delete syslog it is ok or make some things wrong in system ?!

Comment: @rrr171 I would do this: `tail -n 500 /var/log/syslog | sudo tee -a /var/log/syslog.snip` then run `echo "" | sudo tee /var/log/syslog` and it'l clean up your syslog.  The reason I want the snippet is because if your system is generating *that* many log messages on a regular basis, then something's likely busted on your computer.

Comment: Once you get these commands, take the contents of `/var/log/syslog.snip` that we created and copy/paste the contents into your question as an edit.

Comment: Great ... Thank you .. I restore 260GB

Comment: @rrr171 I strongly advise you to share the log snippet I asked for - this is because we want to help you solve *why* your system is filling logs insanely - it's likely some errors or such we can help you solve.

Comment: Something similar to `$ sudo journalctl --vacuum-time=10d` - might also be in place.

Comment: @Thomas Ward ... Yes ... I think there is some things wrong .. I'm using bitbake to compile and build Dreambox images .. and every time I restart ubuntu and try to build image I get the `/var/log/syslog` very large space ... How can I stop it ?!!

Comment: @rrr171 start by determining the errors being dropped into your syslog.  You can't stop the syslog from being written to and my guess is you've got your system dumping tons of data into your syslog.  Start by grabbing a snippet of the logs and including what those are here in an edit to your question like I asked for two days ago.

Comment: Sorry for late and thank you ... I think better to move to 22.10 ?!!